# formSelect() method in materialize does'nt work in angular 6 inputs

Tags: angular, materialize

I'm using materialize CSS combined with angular 6,  my problem is that the input's label if they load data from some services, the label overlaps with the text of the input.

In their official documentation, they use this code to fix this behaviour:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').formSelect();
  });
```

but if i use this code in the ngOnInit() or even  the  ngAfterViewInit(), it fails with this error:

> error TS2339: Property 'formSelect' does not exist on type
>   'JQuery'.

I have Jquery imported, obviously is not detecting the materialize script.
I tried importing the script from CDN and in the angular.json like this:

```
 "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css"       
            ],
            "scripts": [  
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"]
```

What do I need to do to fix this? looks that's the angular app is not loading the script or if it's loading the script, it's too early to call the function.

Comment: Can you tell what is `formSelect()` method for?

Comment: from the official site of materializeCss is used to initialize the select element, tried to search in the materialize.js but no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have imported jquery like this:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

try this instead:

```
$: any // declare dollar sign as a field variable
```

The reason it should work is when you are importing `$` from `jquery` it looks for `formSelect()` method in jquery method but it's a `materialize.js` method. when you declare `$` as an `any` your code compiles successfully and now because you've added `jquery` and `materialize.js` to your **scripts** in your **angular.json** in the application run it recognizes `.formSelect()` on `$`